# Storing Locale to CoreData Swiftui

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, locale, region

I would like to store the Locale to Core Data that I can assign it against a list item. Thus when a user changes a locale the formatting of the original currency etc. is not impacted by the change and thus the app still functions.

I think this would be something useful, even if a user would not typically change the region often.

I have defined a currency formatter using current locale settings:

```
var currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
   return formatter
}()
```

I have a function that uses this to a. format a currency and b. strip it for processing:

```
func formatCurrency(text: String, edit: Bool, currencyCode: String) -> String {
        if(!edit && text.count > 0) {
             let myDouble = (text as NSString).doubleValue
             let myNumber = NSNumber(value:myDouble)
            let priceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: myNumber) ?? "0.00"
             print(priceString)
             return priceString
        } else {
            let myDouble = (text as NSString).doubleValue
            let myNumber = NSNumber(value:myDouble)
            let returnValue = currencyFormatter.number(from: text) ?? myNumber
            if(returnValue == 0){
                return ""
            }
            return returnValue.stringValue
        }
    }
```

I have tried to save the 'currencyFormatter.currencyCode` in Core Data as a text, this works, however since you need to consider symbols for decimal, and separators etc. this becomes clumsy as there are lots of parameters. Below are a few:

```
print("currencyDecimalSeparator - " + currencyFormatter.currencyDecimalSeparator)
 print("currencySymbol - " + currencyFormatter.currencySymbol)
 print("currencyGroupingSeparator - " + currencyFormatter.currencyGroupingSeparator)
 print("internationalCurrencySymbol - " + currencyFormatter.internationalCurrencySymbol)
 print("currencyCode - " + currencyFormatter.currencyCode)
 print("decimalSeparator - " + currencyFormatter.decimalSeparator)
```

I would like to have a neat way of storing `Locale.current` that I can assign it back when accessing a specific list item.

Thank you,
Etienne

Comment: I would like to see your code at first.

Comment: Comments are not a place for code - just edit your post and add your code in it

Comment: Locale has an identifier property of type String, why don’t you store that. But the whole idea seems wrong to me, if the user change locale then having mixed formats would be very confusing.

Comment: Hi Joakim, idea is to keep whatever loan you have added for the currency you had at that point in time. As if you do change you region the load you added at that point in time is still valid for that country and locale settings. I think the juice might not be worth the squeeze as realistically people would not change their region often if ever. But worth while trying to see if there is a simple solution...

Comment: Thank you. I’m going to try to set the locale identifier. Found the below article: https://onmyway133.github.io/blog/How-to-specify-locale-in-Swift/

Comment: If you want to support amounts etc for different currencies then store the currency together with the amount and not the Locale. In my opinion you should have the same format for numbers no matter the currency.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.

Solution as follow:

1. I stored the locale identifier in Core Data against my entity that I use to populate a `List`:

   @State var localeIdentifier = Locale.current.identifier
2. When I want to format the currency, I use the stored identifier to initiate a new locale for my formatter:

   currencyFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: localeIdentifier)